# Como executar uma instrução SQL concatenada com uma variável em uma Procedure no MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Estou criando uma procedure para criar uma base e algumas tabelas dentro dessa base. Eu recebo o nome da base a ser criada por parâmetro.

Estou com dificuldade em concatenar esse parâmetro junto ao script de criação da tabela.

Abaixo segue o código do que fiz:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE criar_base_empresa(IN empresa VARCHAR(14))
  BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS empresa;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empresa.`notas` (
      `id`        INT(11)     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `dtEmissao` DATE        NOT NULL,
      `modelo`    CHAR(2)     NOT NULL,
      `valor`     FLOAT(9, 2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

  END //

CALL criar_base_empresa('99999999999')
```

Se eu executar, a base que é criada é 'empresa' e não '99999999999'.

Vale ressaltar que o nome do banco possui somente números, então teria que colocar o nome do banco entre ``(apóstrofos).

Comment: Nada feito @Francisco, ele da erro de sintaxe.